# SQL - Return minimum value of columns for each row

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, min

I need to select the minimum value of 3 columns for each row in a SQL table. The table is thousands of rows. I am using MySQL.

```
User   val1    val2    val3
1      1       2       5 
2      3       3       3
3      0       1       0
```

Returns

```
User    minimum_value
1       1
2       3
3       0
```

Every search just shows me the MIN() function which is for finding the minim value for an entire column over ALL rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [`least` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least):

```
select least(val1, val2, val3) from your_table;
```